# How to pass constructor parameters to solc?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, solc, bytecode

I'm trying to compile a Smart Contract to bytecode using solc.
I'm on a Ubuntu VM so I have to rely on a simple-to-install cmd line application.

Compilation works fine but it seems like I can't pass any input parameter for the constructor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is accurate. Solc serves only to compile a solidity written contract into Bytecode and ABI ... After having these you must use a Client (Infura, Parity, Geth, etc..) to deploy the contract. This is where you provide Arguments to your constructor

Comment: Thank you. I will mark @goodvibration 's answer as correct and create a new, more accurate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor arguments are passed during deployment, not during compilation.